# Selenium throws an error getting the current URL

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

Trying to scrape a webpage for data, I check the current URL to make sure I'm on the expected page. However, it eventually raises an error and it seems to be when checking the URL. I can't figure out why, and when it happens isn't consistent. Sometimes it's several pages into the script, sometimes it's only a few pages in.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scrape.py", line 5, in <module>
    scraper.start_search("ebook")
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/scraper/school/scraper.py", line 56, in start_search
    self.scrape_item(product_el)
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/scraper/school/scraper.py", line 97, in scrape_item
    if self.driver.current_url.split("/")[3] != "search":
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 493, in current_url
    return self.execute(Command.GET_CURRENT_URL)['value']
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 415, in execute
    return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 489, in _request
    resp = opener.open(request, timeout=self._timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 404, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 422, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1214, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1184, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 111] Connection refused>
```

The seemingly relevant code is just:

```
if self.driver.current_url.split("/")[3] != "search":
            time.sleep(random.randint(1, 3))
            self.driver.back()
```

I'm using Python 2.7, Selenium, and PhantomJS.

Comment: Have you tried other solutions on [so] with the keywords `111 Connection refused selenium python`? There are eight results, half of which have accepted answers.

Comment: @TemporalWolf yes, and none of those solutions help me

Comment: Have  you verified that the url is actually what you think it is? If you copy and paste that exact url into a browser, does it work? Does the URL require authentication?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this is happening, though I have also seen `current_url` be flaky. Have you tried mitigating this with some exception handling?

```
from retry import retry
from urllib2 import URLError


@retry(URLError, tries=3)
def get_url(driver):
    return driver.current_url


def main():
    # Whatever setup you have goes here
    # <...>

    if get_url(driver).split("/")[3] != "search":
        time.sleep(random.randint(1, 3))
        driver.back()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

[The `retry` package is available from PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/retry)